# CSS fullscreen background shows whitebar at bottom when scrolling on mobile

Tags: html, css, background

I have a website with a fullscreen background image.

```
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

html {
  background: url('/img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This code works fine on most devices, but on some old Android devices, this causes a problem when scrolling down. Partially scrolling down, but not releasing your finger shows a white bar equal in size to the URL bar that is disappearing at the same time. Once you release your finger the background fixes itself.

This is what the image looks like mid-scroll.

[image: screenshot of website]

Is there a way to make sure the background is always filling the page?

---

**Edit:** I have also tried adding a div with these properties:

```
#background {
  background: url('/img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

This shows the background but the same problem occurs.

Comment: did you try this with `body{height: 100%}`?

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid Yes, I have. It has no effect since the content of the page always fills over 100% anyway.

Comment: Try [scroll-snap](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/) to look it in place :)

Comment: @myjobistobehappy Could you explain how that property could be used to solve my problem?

Comment: @JulianLachniet, try `position: fixed`

Comment: @myjobistobehappy I did it, doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Does the answers in this question help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532327/background-attachmentfixed-not-working-android-chrome-v40

Comment: Try setting the `height` to 100% where you have `background` property

Comment: @sagar1025 It makes no difference.

Comment: does the `background-attachment` has to be `fixed`? have you tried removing or changing the different `background- attachment` values?

Comment: @sagar1025 Changing that property fixes the problem but I'm trying to figure out how to avoid changing the layout.

Comment: I have found that it is the safari browser. You can do it on any page.

Comment: Care to provide browser/Android version?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use -webkit-fill-available

   https://css-tricks.com/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/
2. I had a similar problem that I had to calculate the height of a body without safari toolbar. came up with this solution. Don't Know if its working for you too or not:

   body {
   height: 100vh;
   height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
   }

Answer (score 0):

On IOS and newer Android devices, vh has been fixed so that 100vh is always the height between the bottom of the minimal top bar and the bottom of the screen.

In older devices this was not so, so vh changes when the user gets rid of some of the browsers top bars by scrolling.

This fixing was introduced to stop the phenomenon you are seeing, and potential ‘jumping’ in size of elements when scrolling. It has introduced another problem which is that not all your background will show when the user first enters the page.

In your case this isn’t noticeable because of the solid color for some distance at the bottom of your image. It would matter if there was text near the bottom.

You could perhaps get round your problem by having an absolutely placed element, or a pseudo element, which had the same background but at 100vh plus a bit. This might work, ie. it give a visible join, given the nature of your image.

Not a general solution though, I realise.

Comment: I have tried adding the background as a fixed position <div> underneath the whole page. Even with that I still see the white bar.

Comment: I wasn’t thinking of fixed position, but absolute and with a larger height and extra to the code you already have, not instead of. What height did the extra div have?If that doesn’t do it,  a pseudo element should.

Comment: I edited the question to show my code. I have the same problem there. I'm not sure what you mean by pseudo element,

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: Is that any different that what the other answer suggested with `body::after`? It has the same problem as just adding a `<div>` to the body.

Comment: Yes it is different. The other answer constrains the size to 100vh height so you are going to have the same problem  - the 100vh when you first enter the page is not as long as the 100vh once you have scrolled so it's not enough to use it. Also have you tried your site on an IOS device? IOS Safari does not support fixed in background attachment. I think you probably need to put up a working snippet which definitely shows the problem, using your background image, to see if we can reproduce it.

Comment: I did not try the fixed position on iOS. A live version of the site is at http://thirteenthofmarch.com/ with CS at https://thirteenthofmarch.com/css/app.css

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a pseudo element, it might be a bit work  do to, but it could potentially fix the issue, like so

```
html, body {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}

body::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url('/img/background.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I can't set the html and body to 100vh and 100vw without breaking the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know how to do this, so I looked it up. <kbd>Safari</kbd> has the tendency to do this on all websites, but you may be able to fix it for your case. I have found a few **similar** questions on <kbd>Stack Overflow</kbd> on how to fix it. I will present some of the solutions below:

#### Add a scroll class to your background

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll {
 overflow: auto;
 height: 100%;
}
```

#### Prevent overflow scrolling

```css
html,
body {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```

#### Using the iNoBounce Library

This library can be found [here](https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce). This should be your last resort in the case that the other methods don't work. The owners have not released a new update since 2018, but for now it has worked through my tests. Happy Coding :)

Comment: This does not make a difference.

Comment: @JulianLachniet, hmm, I will look for another solution.

Comment: @JulianLachniet, I made an update. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will make your background always filling the page

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

html {
  background: url('/img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This breaks the layout of the page and does not solve the problem.

Comment: never set the `position` of the `html` element to `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
html {
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

This is suggested in the below link question, which seems is similar to your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47372972/6119844

Answer (score 0):

try this : 420 is a common mobile screen size.
??? is based on your elements height

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .sampleCSSclass {
    height: calc(100vh - ????px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the scrollbar is totaly not used you can add oveflow hidden to body and no overflow will be vissible. Try to set margin and padding to 0

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `height: 100vh;` You need to increase height. Maybe you should try `height:100%` or try `min-height: 100vh;`

Comment: did it help you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is background-attachment: fixed;
Things work fine if the image scrolls with the div it belongs to, but as soon as its fixed it takes up 100vh.

Ive been at this for longer then i'd like to admit and havent found a solution yet.

It seemingly just doesnt not want to listen to the actual div height; In my case, (using background-size: cover;) the innerHeight (100vh) reads 653px when the toolbar is active, and 709px when the toolbar disappears.

While typing this i did a simple test (on Firefox mobile:

So i used fixed height and auto width on the background image, using an image that has a simple red line at the bottom:

1. Using height: 653 - the red line in the image shows (obviously)
2. Using height 709 - the red line does not show when the toolbar disappears!

Which means that the pixels obstructed by the toolbar are just simply not being rendered when the toolbar disappears. Event though they should in my logic..

EDIT:
I thought i had a solution: place a div behind the rest of the site that holds (and stacks if you have a background per section like i do) in a wrapper. Set this to absolute and use javascript to get the element's offset top (of which the background is supposed to belong to) and offset the background's "top" property to be equal the the div it belongs to.
I tried using the offsetTop property to match the offsets, but havent made it work yet.

But theoretical, one could then use position sticky on the background images to mimic the position fixed effect without content jumps or the annoying (seeming) bug.